# Неактивная кнопка GUI в Unity

Tags: unity3d, gui

Как создать неактивную кнопку GUI и активировать/деактивировать её? Есть GUI.enabled, но она отрубает всё, что идёт после неё, а если использовать это несколько раз, то GUI перестает работать. Есть еще GUI.Button.enabled, но когда я пытаюсь с этим что-нибудь сделать, редактор пишет, что это можно использовать только как метод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил проблему сам. Надо было после манипуляций с деактивацией через GUI.enabled в конце поставить GUI.enabled = true; чтобы GUI продолжал работу и не зависал.
Пример:

```
bool ButtonEnabled = false;

GUI.enabled = ButtonEnabled;
if (GUI.Button(...)) {...}
GUI.enabled = true;
```

И так с любым элементом GUI.

Answer (score 2):

```
public GameObject buttonAboutGame;
```

[1) Включение и отключение возможности выбора выбираемого элемента](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html)

```
buttonAboutGame.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
buttonAboutGame.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
```

[2)Активация и деактивация объекта](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html)

```
buttonAboutGame.SetActive(true);
buttonAboutGame.SetActive(false);
```

Меня правильно поправили, что речь не о UI, а о GUI.
Тогда, мое мнение, что

> создать неактивную кнопку GUI и активировать/деактивировать её

никак.
Описание: bool GUI.Button(Rect pos, string text) Make a single press button. The user clicks them and something happens immediately.
То же самое, что методом, создающим зелёные яблоки, пытаться создать оранжевые апельсины.
Для решения этой проблемы можно создать имитацию кнопки, например, создать картинку и её размещать вместо кнопки. 
Или **использовать другие элементы (label и box)** и [**стилизировать под кнопку**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUISkin.html):

```
GUIStyle buttonStyle = GUI.skin.GetStyle("Button");
GUI.Box(rectBox, "Box муляж", buttonStyle);
if (GUI.Button(rectButton, "Button Кнопка"))
{
    print("Кнопка");
}
GUI.Label(rectMoulage, "Label Муляж", buttonStyle);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Button реагирует на наведение и нажатие, box - только на наведение, label ни на что не реагирует. Соответственно, при необходимости "активировать" "кнопку" заменяете, например, box на button, и при "деактивации" button на, например, label.

Comment: Автор пишет про GUI, а не о новом UI

Comment: Спасибо, добавил про GUI.